# How to access a DataTemplate in C#

Tags: windows, windows-8

I get confused with Windows 8, as I get used to access a template that i had defined in page like this :

```
  FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
  DataTemplate myTemplate = element.FindResource("myTemplate") as DataTemplate;
```

The problem is that in Windows 8 the FindResource method doesn't seem to exist anymore. I try to access the Resource Dictionnary but without any success.

Do you have any idea, or Should the previous example work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrameworkElement has a [Resources property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) that you can access through it's indexer like so:

```
var template = element.Resources["myTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

This property is only populated with the resources defined on that element and is not the full collection of resources in the Application. So whether that template will be found depends on where you've defined in.

You can find the resources defined in App.xaml (as well as it's merged resource dictionaries) like so:

```
var template = Application.Current.Resources["myTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

Comment: Thank you it works well. I found out why i get this problem it's just because I was using a DataTemplateSelector and it needs to be linked to template defined in the page ressources like this :

'<local:AuctionItemDataTemplateSelector x:Key="mySelector"
                                     FirstDataTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate1}"
                                     SecondDataTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate2}">
        </local:AuctionItemDataTemplateSelector> 

Thank you for your answer